# Different command prompts for user and root

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ssh

I'm using putty client in windows to connect to remote Debian 6 via SSH. If I login as root I have normal command prompt like `root@ion:~#` and command autocomplete works fine when press `tab`. 
In case I log as not root user I have only `$` in command prompt and no command autocomplete.

Why it is so and how to expand not root user possibilities?

Comment: Are you sure your non-root user's login shell on the remote system is set to `bash` - not a different shell such as `dash`?

Comment: This depends on the type of shell you have and its configuration. The root prompt is by tradition `#` to be significantly different from the traditional non-root prompt `$`.  What shell are you using as the non-root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you login run the command `ps` as each user it will tell you which shell is being invoked. See if they are both bash.

If they are both bash, you could execute the builtin `complete` and see if that turns on autocompletion in bash. If that fixes the problem , just add complete to your users .bashrc

As for the prompt, that is a function of the environment variable `PS1` run the command `echo $PS1` and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find your shell by typing *echo $SHELL* also, I would *cat /etc/password* to see what shell that it's set to.
Also, you can run chsh, to change your shell.